# In css whats the difference between element.class and element<space>.class

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to work out why my css wasn't working when I had

```
mydiv .myclass { font-size: 24px !important; }
```

and I just happened to try

```
mydiv.myclass { font-size: 24px !important; }
```

and the formatting worked.

What's the difference between the two?

Comment: Do you really have a `<mydiv>` element?

Comment: err.. no. good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Without the space it means:** apply to div elements with the "myclass" class.
**With the space it means:** apply to elements with "myclass" class which are inside a div.

```
/*Apply to div elements with the 'container' class*/
div.container{
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;    
}

/*Apply to elements with 'container' class which are inside a div*/
div .container{
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: red;    
}
```

**EXAMPLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/gdxva1k0/

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 2):

The space in the first case is a descendant combinator. For example, p .center, would mean an element within a p tag and has class center;

An example for the second one could be p.center, which means all p tag with center class.

Comment: DISAGREE: If it were an OR then it would have worked.

Comment: This answer is not correct. Why does it have 2 upvotes?

Comment: Agreed. This answer is incorrect.

Comment: @Vohuman because you didn't downvote it? If you know an answer is incorrect, it is your duty as an SO user to point this out (and a high-rep one too)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt First of all, I don't have any "duties" here. I upvote/downvote/answer whenever I want/can, just like other normal users. "to point this out"? I have. And I did downvote. The answer was edited. The updated answer was correct,  and I removed my downvote.

Answer (score 2):

This `div.myclass` targets every `div` which also has `.myclass`.

While `div .myclass` will target every element inside `div` tag (at any node depth) with class `.myclass` (AKA **descendant selector)**.

furthermore..

There is also `div >.myclass` which targets all elements with `.myclass` which are directly children of `div` (AKA **child selector**).

Then there are **adjacent sibling selector** (`div +.myclass`)which allow to select an element that is directly after another specific element.

Concluding there's also `div ~.myclass` which is a **general sibling combinator selector**; it is very similar to the adjacent sibling combinator selector ; the difference is that that the element being selected doesn't need to immediately succeed the first element, but can appear anywhere after it.

Answer (score 1):

With the space, it infers a child element of the parent. So

```
div span
```

Is any span that is the child of a div.  A class can't be a child.  That's why it didn't work.

```
tag.class
```

Means all elements of type tag and with class .class will take the style.

Comment: I think the clarification here that "a class can't be a child" explains this  nicely.

Answer (score 0):

The first says actually the following:
Select every .myclass thats inside a mydiv element (direct and indirect children).

The second one says:
Select every mydiv element that has a class attribute of myclass

You can find a good reference [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)